# How to make a searchable droplist in react native to open an specific screen?

Tags: react-native, listview, routes

I'm trying to make a search bar with a list,dropdown list,
[image]

[image]

how to make a search list lik this code:

```
 onPress={() =>this.props.navigation.navigate('LinhaDiurno03')
```

when an item is pressed?

....I want that each item in the list open a different screen in the application....

How can i to it?

here is the my teste:

[Code to dropDown List](https://snack.expo.io/@matheus_cbrl/teste)

here some code:

```
 var items = [
  //name key is must.It is to show the text in front
  {id: 1, name: 'ANA RECH', prestadora: 'UNIDOS', pos: 'P01'},
  {id: 2, name: 'ARROIO DAS MARRECAS', prestadora: 'UNIDOS', pos: 'P01'},
  {id: 3, name: 'VILA SECA', prestadora: 'UNIDOS', pos: 'P01'},];

 onItemSelect={item => Alert.alert(" ", JSON.stringify(item.prestadora + ", LINHA: " + item.pos), [{ text: "open the especifc screen", onPress: () =>('some code here')},{ text: "bacvk", onPress: () => console.log("OK Pressed")}],{ cancelable: true })}
  //onItemSelect called after the selection from the dropdown
```

Comment: I'm using mobile right now so I can't see your code right, so How you render your data? Using FlatList?

Comment: I render with array list = var items = [x,y,z ....], but i do not know hor to make a propertie route each one of the list itens to open diferent screens in the app...

Comment: To be sure, you want when I open search and when u press to any item from the search result navigate me to a specific screen right?

Comment: yes, that's the way... if you help me, i will be so glad!!!!

Comment: @Lenoarod try to use his answer and let me know if couldn't help you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I read the library API, you can set the navigation keys in the item, then in the `onItemSelect`  to go to the special screen. the example code is below.

```
// in the item every element add a router key
const item = [
...
{
    id: 8,
    name: 'Swift',
    key:"the navigation params" //like the example LinhaDiurno03
  },
...
]

<SearchableDropdown
            multi={true}
            selectedItems={this.state.selectedItems}
            onItemSelect={(item) => {
              his.props.navigation.navigate(item.key)
            }}
/>
```

Comment: Hi @Lenoarod, i am doing somothing wrong... I got the follow errror: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'this.props.navigation')

Comment: I did it :  { id: 1, name: 'ANA RECH', prestadora: 'UNIDOS', pos: 'P01', key: this.props.navigation.navigate('LinhaDiurno03') },

Comment: In the key you just pass a name 'LinhaDiurno03'

Comment: I show an example, you should according to your actual situation to handle it .

Comment: @Matheus cabral, is it the solution successful?

Comment: Hi, the code not worked.. iwirute like this :   { id: 1, name: 'ANA RECH', prestadora: 'UNIDOS', pos: 'P01', key: "Sobre" }, 
but the comand do not change ro the other screen.. I writed right:?

Comment: did you have set router, if not, you should firstly set them

Comment: I'm sorry i forgot that .. :/ Now it Works, I really thank you!! I'm so glad!!!

Answer (score 0):

Here is the final code, you just need to make the route before in your app...
[the full code](https://snack.expo.io/@matheus_cbrl/dropdown)